# ES6 object destructuring with a default value assignment

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Consider the following code:

```
const log = ({a,b=a}) => console.log(a,b);
log({a:'a'})
```

The variable `b` is assigned the value `a`. This does work when transpiling it to es5, but I am not entirely sure if this is valid es6 syntax.

Am I allowed to do this kind of default value assignment in a destructured object?

Comment: this does not work ... outputs `undefined,undefined` **as expected**

Comment: I don't understand what you expect, because you're passing a string instead of an object to be destructured. Works for me just fine with an object. `log({a: "x"})` gives `x x`.

Comment: @JaromandaX: Why do you say it doesn't work when it   gives an expected output?

Comment: I mean as expected from the code ... the description suggests b is assigned the value a ... which, I guess is true, as they are both undefined, but, the statement is unclear -

Comment: So I made a typo, updated the code

Answer (score 1):

```
const log = ({a,b=a}) => console.log(a,b);
log('a')
```

is syntactically valid but semantically invalid, since you are trying to destructure a string primitive, which gets boxed into a temporary `String` object wrapper, and tries to get both `a` and `b` properties, which are always `undefined` since the wrapper object is temporary and only created for the sake of the operation triggering the boxing itself.

Thus you have `undefined, undefined` when you call it.

The destructuring operation with defaults could be semantically valid
in your case with a call like this:

```
const log = ({a,b=a}) => console.log(a,b);
log({a: 'a'}) // a,a
```

**UPD:**

But beware that order of supplying default value matters, so this won't
work

```
const log = ({a=b,b}) => console.log(a,b);
log({a: 'a'}) // error
```

because destructuring happens after argument object initialization and is evaluated from left to right, thus `b` is not yet destructured and known by the time we destructure `a` to try to reference it in case `a` is undefined.

Comment: This was exactly what I meant in my post (typo). So this is correct syntax? Order seems trivial? I.e.: `({a=b,b})` is valid as well?

Comment: Order matters, since destructuring happens after argument object initialisation and is evaluated from left to right. Updated the answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I allowed to do this kind of default value assignment in a destructured object?

Yes. The destructuring expression is evaluated from left to right, and you can use variables that are already initialised from properties in the default initialiser expressions of later properties.

Remember that it desugars to

```
const log = (o) => {
  var a = o.a;
  var b = o.b !== undefined ? o.b : a;
//                                  ^ a is usable here
  console.log(a,b);
};
```